# How to handle error nodejs JavaScript catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth

```
var result;

    async function verify() {
      const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  
    });
    }

     verify().catch(console.error);
```

If there is an error, 
I want to set

```
var result = 'fail';
```

if there is no error,
I want to set:

```
var result = 'success';
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It would be nice I you either accept answer or say why it does not address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making your `verify` to return such result value? Then inside of it you can wrap your client function with try-catch:

```
async function verify() {
    try {
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken(...);
        return 'success';
    } catch(err) {
        // probably some extra logging here
        return 'fail';
    }
}

...

var result = await verify(); // will be either success or fail
```